# Wrote a WP Cron Plugin and it triggers a fatal error upon activation

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, wp-insert-post, api, wp-cron

I'm writing a WP Plugin for one of my sites that hooks into a public API to get app data and save that within Wordpress to allow for WP to be able to search & filter the data based on new parameters created in Wordpress as well as parameters from the API.

When I try and activate the plugin, I get a warning message through the `/wp-admin/plugins.php` that states

> Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a **fatal error**.

```
    // Register cb Cron Jobs Activation & Add to Cron Queue
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'cb_cron_jobs_activation');
    add_action('my_hourly_event', 'cb_app_post_type_sync');

    function cb_cron_jobs_activation() {
      wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event' );  
    }

    // Update "app" Custom Post Type with cb App Market API Sync
    function cb_app_post_type_sync() {

      if ( post_type_exists('app') ){



        /* ================================================================
        ** GET & USE MERCHANT PLANS API
        *  ================================================================ */

        // GET API info from MerchantPlans for bundle details for above apps
        $merchantplans_get_response = wp_remote_get( 'https://www.cb.com/v3/merchant_plans?expand=modules' );

        $merchantplans_api_body_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $merchantplans_get_response ), true );


        // Disect merchant_plans objects
        $merchantplans_elements = $merchantplans_api_body_response['elements'];

        // Generate 3 arrays with module key=>value pairs: classic_bundle, terminal_bundle, register_bundle
        foreach ( $merchantplans_elements as $merchantplans_element ) {

          // Convert merchant bundle name into lowercase joined by underscores for better calling into taxonomies later
          $merchantplan_lowercase = strtolower($merchantplans_element['name']);
          $merchantplan_underscores = str_replace(' ', '_', $merchantplan_lowercase);
          ${$merchantplan_underscores} = array();

          // set variable for each merchant bundle module
          $merchantplans_modules_elements = $merchantplans_element['modules']['elements'];

          // add each marchant bundle module into the array of the associated merchant bundle with the id as the key in the key => value pair
          foreach( $merchantplans_modules_elements as $merchantplans_modules_element ) {
            ${$merchantplan_underscores}[$merchantplans_modules_element['id']] = $merchantplans_modules_element['name'];
          }

        }

        // find the difference between the register_bundle's modules & the terminal_bundle's modules
        $register_unique_modules = array_diff( $register_bundle, $terminal_bundle );
        // This is useful later when we are checking to see which apps belong in which bundles


        /* ================================================================
        ** GET & USE APPMARKET API TO SYNC APP INFO
        *  ================================================================ */

        // GET API info from apps for App Market details
        $appmarket_get_response = wp_remote_get( 'https://www.cb.com/v3/apps?expand=modules%2CavailableMetereds%2CavailableSubscriptions%2CdeviceTypes&filter=approvalStatus%3DPUBLISHED&filter=hidden%3Dfalse' );

        $appmarket_api_body_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $appmarket_get_response ), true );

        // Unpack the $appmarket_api_body_response array & Build a table to show the data
        $apps_elements = $appmarket_api_body_response['elements'];

        // Run through every app returned in the appmarket API Get request and either update the "app" post type or create a new "app" in WP
        foreach ($apps_elements as $apps_element) {

          // Define the Available Subscription Arrays and Available Metered Arrays
          $available_subscription_elements = $apps_element['availableSubscriptions']['elements'];
          $available_metered_elements = $apps_element['availableMetereds']['elements'];

          // sort Availabe Subscription Arrays & return in lowest to highest amount order
          $subscription_amount_tmp = array();
          foreach( $available_subscription_elements as $key => &$element_row) {
              $subscription_amount_tmp[$key] = &$element_row['subscriptionCountries']['elements'][0]['amount'];
          }
          array_multisort($subscription_amount_tmp, $available_subscription_elements);

          // sort Available Metered Arrays & return in lowest to highest amount order
          $metered_amount_tmp = array();
          foreach( $available_subscription_elements as $key => &$element_row) {
              $metered_amount_tmp[$key] = &$element_row['meteredCountries']['elements'][0]['amount'];
          }
          array_multisort($metered_amount_tmp, $available_subscription_elements);

          // define the apps modules for comparing with the modules in register & terminal bundles to determine which bundle it belongs in
          $third_party_module_elements = $apps_element['modules']['elements'];

          // Count the modules per app and compare with modules in $register_unique_modules array
          // this allows us to determine if the app uses the register plan or the terminal plan
          $module_count = 0;
          foreach ( $third_party_module_elements as $third_party_module_element ) {
            if ( in_array( $third_party_module_element['name'], $register_unique_modules )) {
                $module_count++;
            }
          }
          if ($module_count > 0) {
              $associated_app_plan = 'register-bundle';
          } else {
              $associated_app_plan = 'terminal-bundle';
          }
          /*
          $app_delete_query = array(
            'post_type' => 'app',
            );
          */

          // Query the existing 'app' post type to see if apps exist with the proper app_id.
          $app_update_args = array(
            'post_type' => 'app',
            'name' => 'us-' . $apps_element['id'],
          );
          $app_update_query = new WP_Query( $app_update_args );

          // if the app exists check to see if the following values are the same and if not update them
          if ( $app_update_query->have_posts() ) : 
            while ( $app_update_query->have_posts() ) : $app_update_query->the_post();

              $app_in_wpdb = array(
                'ID'             => get_the_ID();
                'post_title'     => $apps_element['name'],
                'post_content'   => $apps_element['description'],
                'post_name'      => 'us-' . $apps_element['id'],    // The name (slug) for your post
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'post_type'      => 'app',
                'post_author'    => 1,
                'menu_order'     => $apps_element['sortOrder'],
                'tax_input'      => array( 'cb_plan' => $associated_app_plan ) // GET API info from apps for App Market details
              );

              wp_insert_post( $app_in_wpdb );

              if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
                $errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                  echo $error;
                }
              }

            endwhile;

          // if the app doesn't exist, create the 'app' post, and fill with the following values
          else:

            $new_app_in_wpdb = array(
                'post_title'     => $apps_element['name'],          // The title of your post.
                'post_content'   => $apps_element['description'],   // The full text of the post.
                'post_name'      => 'us-' . $apps_element['id'],    // The name (slug) for your post
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'post_type'      => 'app',
                'post_author'    => 1,
                'menu_order'     => $apps_element['sortOrder'],
                'tax_input'      => array( 'cb_plan' => $associated_app_plan ) // GET API info from apps for App Market details
              );
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_app_in_wpdb );

            if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
                $errors = $post_id->get_error_messages();
                foreach ($errors as $error) {
                  echo $error;
                }
              }
              // add app icon to WP Uploads Directory & then attach as featured image to post
              $image_url  = $apps_element['filenameIconLarge']; // Define the image URL here
              $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir(); // Set upload folder
              $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url); // Get image data
              $filename   = basename($image_url); // Create image file name

              // Check folder permission and define file location
              if( wp_mkdir_p( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
                  $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
              } else {
                  $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
              }

              // Create the image  file on the server
              file_put_contents( $file, $image_data );

              // Check image file type
              $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename, null );

              // Set attachment data
              $attachment = array(
                  'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                  'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( $filename ),
                  'post_content'   => '',
                  'post_status'    => 'inherit'
              );

              // Create the attachment
              $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

              // Include image.php
              require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

              // Define attachment metadata
              $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );

              // Assign metadata to attachment
              wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

              // And finally assign featured image to post
              set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );

              // update public_app_url
              $public_app_url = 'https://www.cb.com/appmarket/apps/' . $apps_element['id'];
              update_field( 'field_550c63cc17698', $public_app_url, $post_id );

              // update app market ID
              update_field( 'field_55dcf06582888', $apps_element['id'], $post_id);

              if ( !empty($available_subscription_elements) ) {
                // update available subscriptions
                $subscription_field_key = "field_55dd0bbdccfe6";
                $subscription_value = get_field($subscription_field_key, $post_id);

                foreach ( $available_subscription_elements as $available_subscription_element ) {
                  $country_specific_available_subscriptions = $available_subscription_element['subscriptionCountries']['elements'];

                  foreach ( $country_specific_available_subscriptions as $country_specific_available_subscription ) {
                      $subscription_value[] = array('field_55dd0beaccfe7' => $country_specific_available_subscription['id'], 'field_55dd0c1bccfe8' => $country_specific_available_subscription['name'], 'field_55dd0d6fccfe9' => $country_specific_available_subscription['amount']);
                    }
                }
                update_field( $subscription_field_key, $subscription_value, $post_id );
              }

              if (!empty($available_metered_elements)) {
                // update available metered
                $metered_field_key = "field_55e4f6eda039f";
                $metered_value = get_field($metered_field_key, $post_id);

                foreach ( $available_metered_elements as $available_metered_element ) {
                  $country_specific_available_metered_tiers = $available_metered_element['meteredCountries']['elements'];

                  foreach ( $country_specific_available_metered_tiers as $country_specific_available_metered_tier ) {
                      $metered_value[] = array('field_55e4f6eda03a0' => $country_specific_available_metered_tier['id'], 'field_55e4f6eda03a1' => $country_specific_available_metered_tier['action'], 'field_55e4f6eda03a2' => $country_specific_available_metered_tier['amount']);
                    }
                }
                update_field( $metered_field_key, $metered_value, $post_id );
              }

          endif;

          // Reset Post Data
          wp_reset_postdata();
        }

      }

      // delete all 'app' posts that don't have a matching app ID


    }



    register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'cb_cron_jobs_deactivation');

    function cb_cron_jobs_deactivation() {
      wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_hourly_event');
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Have you enabled WP_DEBUG?

Comment: Yes. This is in my wp-config file

    define('WP_DEBUG', true);
    define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
    define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
    @ini_set('display_errors',0);

Comment: Do you see any errors in your `debug.log` in the wp-content folder?

Comment: I have PHP Warnings & PHP Strict Standards, but none are from the 'cb-cron-jobs' plugin folder or file, all are from other plugins

Answer (score 0):

Disabled all plugins and re-enabled only the necessary ones for this plugin to run correctly (a custom-post-types & custom-taxonomies plugin). Re-activated the plugin and got the error message but with a detail that the line 128 had a semicolon in it. As this was a function being called to get the ID of the element in an array, it should have been followed by a `,` rather than a `;`. Changed this, and activated the plugin successfully.

Moral of the story: Try deactivating plugins that may be interfering with error display & if the error display appears clearly.